# Sharing your answer

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, answers

IMO, it would be nice to have the `linked-In` icon feature to share your answer or question:

[image: share your answer on]

There are only Facebook and Twitter icons, and more social relationship websites could be added.

It could be like area51 sharing options:

[image: Share This]

Comment: Or how about when you up vote something, you also "Like" it?

Comment: No, it is more about advertising PMSE to your friends.

Comment: @Dave - I will never upvote if I have to "Like" everything.  I don't trust Facebook and some of the other social networking sites, and make it a point to never merge or allow my Facebook account to have access to other services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2011, the StackExchange staff ran an experiment where the LinkedIn sharing option was available in the list of networks that a user could choose to use to share a link to the question.

The results were published on [CFO Michael Pryor's Twitter account](https://twitter.com/#!/michaelpryor/status/111516578725629952):

> Over test period StackExchange referrals from Facebook = 12k, Twitter = 11k, LinkedIn = 500. @codinghorror played sad trombone for LinkedIn.

As a result, LinkedIn is not an option. However, there is a [LinkedIn PMSE group](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/a/270/34) which was created to help promote the site.

For more information on the LinkedIn sharing link experiment, please see this [Meta-SO Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83722/share-question-answer-links-to-linkedin).