# Looking for Volunteers to help Contribute to Building the Project Management Community

Tags: discussion

I have created a [Project Management SE Facebook Page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Project-Management-Stack-Exchange-QA/199284413419958?v=wall).

To start, I linked to an article on my blog about Project Management Stack Exchange, as well as Dave Parillo's Web page on Project Management SE.

I also started out by posting links to hot questions on Project Management SE, which quickly became boring.  After more research into social networking and community building, and after reading answers to questions on this site from contributors, I have decided to take a different approach.

I found a funny video from 2006 that relates to the field of Project Management.  I encourage everyone to check it out; I'm sure you'll remember it!  It's the first of many Project Management related material that I plan to regularly publish on this page.  The next few weeks will consist of publishing news articles and videos related to the field, with perhaps the occasional funny parody.

The more followers the Facebook Page gains, the more traffic we can perhaps drive to the Project Management Stack Exchange site.

**Want to Help Out?**

- Everyone here wants to continue to see this community grow.  Please join the Facebook page and help spread the word to other project managers and enthusiasts.
- We have a pool of talented people, already part of this site, who have experience with social networking as a tool for promoting a product.  If you have experience with promotional social networking, or if you want to help promote the site, please help contribute material to the wall of the Facebook page.
- If you have a blog and have posted an article about Project Management SE, please add it to the Wall!
- Let's come up with a social networking strategy that will help this site meet it's goals!

[Project Management SE Statistics and Goals](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10947/project-management)

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but if the goal of the Facebook page is to drive people to this site, why not just do that directly?

Comment: @Marcie - Where and how do you propose finding the people to bring them to this site?  How many Facebook friends do you have?  How many are project managers?  Better yet, I think a LinkedIn profile might be better since it's more geared towards professionals.  How many LinkedIn contacts do you have?  The answer to your question is that our contacts are already on Facebook/LinkedIn, so my plan is that those networks could bridge the gap between them and this site.  I will admit though that I'm not 100% sure I know what I'm doing yet, which is why I'm asking for help.  I want PM SE to succeed.:)

Comment: The main advantage of a network is that it extends beyond just you and I.  Look at [Dave Carroll's "United Breaks Guitars"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5YGc4zOqozo) YouTube Video, which spawned hundreds of blogs, marketing plans, product rebrands, and endorsements for himself, Taylor Guitars, Carlton Cases, and others.  It "went viral".

Comment: I do too, but I only have a couple of PM friends on either Facebook or LinkedIn :)

Comment: @Marcie - "if the goal of the Facebook page is to drive people to this site, why not just do that directly?" Your words of wisdom are ringing true. In the end, this became a battle between trying to gain traffic on PMSE as well as trying to gain followers on the Facebook page. The two efforts diluted one another. Instead, I want to encourage everyone to try out [Jeff Atwood's advice here](http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/a/184/34). We need more people to become ambassadors of PMSE and seek out PM's with project management problems, post their problems here, and send them a link to the answers.

Answer (score 1):

For the past year I have been using the Groups section of Linkedin to connect with other PM professionals and seek for additional answers to my questions.

Not sure what you think about this but I have followed the Facebook initiative and have created an open group on Linkedin to promote the site and post open questions for this site to they get visibility among my PM colleagues. This group does not require invitation or approval so please have a look and let me know your thoughts;

[Project Management Q&A SE](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Project-Management-Q-SE-4281783?home=&gid=4281783&trk=anet_ug_hm)

My intention is feed in questions straight from the PMSE and encourage my connections and new members to come to the site to answer them and earn privileges. If you also join the group and send invitations to your connections the number of members will grow quite rapidly.

What sort of rules or criteria would you like me to take into account to maintain this group?

Comment: Hi, I think this is a great way to help get some exposure and drive more traffic to the site. My suggestion for linking to questions is to use the "link" hyperlink (right below the question tags). This hyperlink will give you credit towards the Announcer, Booster, and Publicist badge, which can give you some feedback as to how you're impacting the site, but that's really up to you. Thanks again for participating :) I encourage everyone to join your group and help spread the word to their colleagues.

Comment: Hi M0N4K0 - I thought I'd check in and see how your LinkedIn site is going? Do you ever encounter any PM problems on your LinkedIn page that could be asked again here? This [Jeff Atwood blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/helping-the-experts-get-answers/) got me thinking about you and how you could be an ambassador between other PM's who have problems and PMSE. In Jeff's blog, he suggests locating problems, asking them here, then sending a link to the PMSE question to that person so they can see the answers.

Comment: Hi jmort253, at the moment the group in Linkedin gets the feeds from the PMSE. We've got few members and I have been thinking in using other PM groups where members do actually ask questions to promote the site. However, I do like your idea of the ambassador role. What would you suggest we do next?

Comment: Jeff suggests taking questions asked by PM's on Twitter, FB, G+, and other forums and creating your own question here. Once it gets answers, send the PMSE question link to the person who had the problem. Jeff's theory is that the PM will see this as a valuable resource. I believe the questions would be better too since avid users are already over the learning curve of how SE works. It seems like a great way to say to people "See! I told you PMSE is great!" and draw them to the site while also contributing real questions here. @PawelBrodzinski was doing something like this for awhile I believe.

Comment: Would you feel comfortable taking questions you find in your travels, cleaning them up to meet SE guidelines for constructiveness, etc and posting them here and evaluate Jeff's theory applied to PMSE?